# d3.js, click action to another URL encoding with array of variables of sunburst

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I made [sequences sunburst visualization](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426) and want to add a link to each path.

I read similar question [d3.js, click to link to another URL encoded with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569225/d3-js-click-to-link-to-another-url-encoded-with-variables) and could make a link based on variable of specific path. (See the code below)
This Code could generate url suck like "http://somelink.com/link.php?id1=CurrentNode".

However, I want to generate url such like "http://somelink.com/link.php?id1=CurrentNode&id2=ParentNode" using hierarchy information.

I do not know very much about javascript, so I need help.

```
// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization(json) {

  // Basic setup of page elements.
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  drawLegend();
  d3.select("#togglelegend");

  // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
  // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
  vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
  var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

  var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("click", function(d) {
              var url = "http://somelink.com/link.php?id1=";
              url += d.name;
              $(location).attr('href', url);
              window.location = url;
            });

  // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
  d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
 };
```

---

I figure out how to make url for three levels sunburst.
To get value based on level of sunburst, I added little modification to the suggestion of Lars.

```
     .on("click", function(d) {
        var url = "http://somelink.com/link.php";
        if (d.depth== 1) {
        　url += "?id1=" + d.name;
        }
        if (d.depth== 2) {
        　url += "?id1=" + (d.parent ? d.parent.name : "");
        　url += "&id2=" + d.name;
        }
        if (d.depth== 3) {
        　url += "?id1=" + (d.parent.parent ? d.parent.parent.name : "");
        　url += "&id2=" + (d.parent ? d.parent.name : "");
        　url += "&id3=" + d.name;
        }
        $(location).attr('href', url);
        window.location = url;
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nodes of a sunburst layout have an attribute `.parent` that contains the parent node (or null for the root). You can use this directly in your code like this:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
          var url = "http://somelink.com/link.php?id1=" + d.name +
                      "?id2=" + (d.parent ? d.parent.name : "");
          $(location).attr('href', url);
          window.location = url;
 });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!  I made sunburst with three levels, so I modified the sunburst to two levels and it's works!